# How to create interactive graphics with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, vector-graphics

I wonder how I can code an application that allows the user to handle simple graphic objects like in a vector graphics program. As a starting point I would like to have a program which allows the user to draw some rectangles, select them with the mouse and move them around.

I have some base knowledge in WinForms but it seems that WPF is a better choice for this task (tell me if you think different. I wouldn't mind using a free graphics library for Winforms as alternative).

I think I know hot to draw a rectangle and how to find out which rectange was clicked by the user. But I don't know how to move the rectangle around with the mouse. Can you give me a hint? I had a look into animations where I could move the rectanle around programatically but I am not sure whether this is the right way to implement it for mouse control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look into PathGeometry. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx).

Combined with a Canvas and some controls you can make a pretty nitty editor ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, the link was indeed helpfull. I was able to move an object around by clicking on a control. I think I will be able to combine it with a mouse click and drag&drop, but this was a helpful starting point!

Comment: Yeah sure you can. You just have to monitor the pointer and get it's delta so that you can bind it to the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left or any other of the properties that suit you best (Right or Bottom). Here's another [doc link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx)